# Why show joined communities count (106) for the Community ♦ moderator when the network profile shows only (1)?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, community-user, network-profile

I know that Community user (♦ moderator) is a background process (and not *really* a person). Upon visiting the "[Community user's Profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile)", I noticed that it has joined 106 communities (see screenshot #1 below) so far. So, out of curiosity, I clicked on the "[View network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=accounts)" to see all the communities in which Community user participates. But I was surprised by the result displayed on the network profile page where it shows that it **only belongs to 1 account** i.e. **Area 51** (Joined 5 years ago, last seen 5 years ago. -- see screenshot #2 below)

I wonder why show joined communities count as 106 (as oppose to just **1**) for the Community user when its network profile has only 1 account? Can anyone please explain this.

Screenshot #1:

> [image]

Screenshot #2:

> [image]

Comment: I searched using different different keyword combinations and search did not bring any similar post... neither at time when I typed the title in the "Asked Question".... But as soon as I post a question... I saw the similar question in "Related" sidebar on the right... Oh well...

Comment: For future reference, those "related" are also the ones you see in the "other questions already asked" under your title *before* you submit your question ;)

Comment: @James definately. I was putting my faith on question title suggestion